# How and where to get access token from oauth2 authorization server?

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, jwt

I am trying to add security to my API with oauth2 and jwt. So currently I can use following command and get access token. 
curl client:secret@localhost:8080/oauth/token -d grant_type=password -d username=user -d password=password

Obviously, I am not going to call it for each user)) My question is that where to call this command? Should I create new service like  "localhost:8080/user/login"  and call this command within my code? (if yes, how?)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grant_type=password` is one of the OAuth 2.0 flows defined in [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) (The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework). To be specific, it is defined in [Section 4.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3). However, the flow is NOT recommended. This means you should not call the command.

In typical cases, web services implement the **Authorization Code** flow defined in [Section 4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1). The following diagram illustrates the flow. See *"[Diagrams And Movies Of All The OAuth 2.0 Flows](https://medium.com/@darutk/diagrams-and-movies-of-all-the-oauth-2-0-flows-194f3c3ade85)"* for details.

[image]

Comment: Your article is great to understand the whole flow. Thank you for that. However, I wanted example Java code to make a call to my auth server and get  token.

Answer (score 0):

normally the reception of the token is done by a configuration (@autoconfigue), the call is made to the server of authentication (provider), here is an example of the configuration oauth2 with a authentication server keycloak, inspire of ca.
available for more information.

https://github.com/bcarun/spring-oauth2-keycloak-connector